# get a tag embedded in table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding to the A tag within a page like so:

```
 $('a').click(function(event) {
      alert('hi');
 });
```

The problem is that every A tag in the page sends the alert.  I only want the A tags within this table below to send the alert.  How do I restrict jquery to only send the alert for the a tags generated in this table?

```
 <table class="add-alert">
  <tbody>
  {% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a id="{{ object.id }}" href="">Click Me</a>
      </td>
     </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delegate it. By delegate, I mean binding it to a static parent, which will administer the click from there to the `a`.

```
$(".add-alert").on("click", "a", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //your stuff
});
```

This will work even if the `a` is dynamic. The reason we're using `e.preventDefault()` here is to prevent the default click of the `a` to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table.add-alert a').click(function(event) {
      alert('hi');
 });
```

Suppose that that's what you mean.